# Spark streaming Kafka messages not consumed

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I want to receive messages from a topic in Kafka (broker v **0.10.2.1**) using Spark (1.6.2) Streaming.

I'm using the **`Receiver`** approach. The code is as following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SimpleStreamingApp");
    JavaStreamingContext javaStreamingContext = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, new Duration(5000));
    //
    Map<String, Integer> topicMap = new HashMap<>();
    topicMap.put("myTopic", 1);
    //
    String zkQuorum = "host1:port1,host2:port2,host3:port3";
    //
    Map<String, String> kafkaParamsMap = new HashMap<>();
    kafkaParamsMap.put("bootstraps.server", zkQuorum);
    kafkaParamsMap.put("metadata.broker.list", zkQuorum);
    kafkaParamsMap.put("zookeeper.connect", zkQuorum);
    kafkaParamsMap.put("group.id", "group_name");
    kafkaParamsMap.put("security.protocol", "SASL_PLAINTEXT");
    kafkaParamsMap.put("security.mechanism", "GSSAPI");
    kafkaParamsMap.put("ssl.kerberos.service.name", "kafka");
    kafkaParamsMap.put("key.deserializer", "kafka.serializer.StringDecoder");
    kafkaParamsMap.put("value.deserializer", "kafka.serializer.DefaultDecoder");
    //
    JavaPairReceiverInputDStream<byte[], byte[]> stream = KafkaUtils.createStream(javaStreamingContext,
                            byte[].class, byte[].class,
                            DefaultDecoder.class, DefaultDecoder.class,
                            kafkaParamsMap,
                            topicMap,
                            StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY());

    VoidFunction<JavaPairRDD<byte[], byte[]>> voidFunc = new VoidFunction<JavaPairRDD<byte[], byte[]>> ()
    {
       public void call(JavaPairRDD<byte[], byte[]> rdd) throws Exception
       {
          List<Tuple2<byte[], byte[]>> all = rdd.collect();
          System.out.println("size of red: " + all.size());
       }
    }

    stream.forEach(voidFunc);

    javaStreamingContext.start();
    javaStreamingContext.awaitTermination();
}
```

Access to Kafka is **kerberized**. When I launch

`spark-submit --verbose --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=jaas.conf"`
`--files jaas.conf,privKey.der`
`--principal <accountName>`
`--keytab <path to keytab file>`
`--master yarn`
`--jars <comma separated path to all jars>`
`--class <fully qualified java main class>`
`<path to jar file containing main class>`

1. `VerifiableProperties` class from Kafka logs **warning** messages for the properties included in the `kafkaParams` hashmap:

> ```
> INFO KafkaReceiver: connecting to zookeeper: <the correct zookeeper quorum provided in kafkaParams map>
>
> VerifiableProperties: Property auto.offset.reset is overridden to largest
> VerifiableProperties: Property enable.auto.commit is not valid.
> VerifiableProperties: Property sasl.kerberos.service.name is not valid
> VerifiableProperties: Property key.deserializer is not valid
> ...
> VerifiableProperties: Property zookeeper.connect is overridden to ....
> ```

I think because these properties are not accepted, so it might be affecting the stream processing.

** when I launch in the cluster mode `--master yarn`, then these warning messages don't appear**

2. Later, I see following logs repeated every 5 seconds as configured:

   `INFO BlockRDD: Removing RDD 4 from persistence list`

   `INFO KafkaInputDStream: Removing blocks of RDD BlockRDD[4] at createStream at ...`

   `INFO ReceivedBlockTracker: Deleting batches ArrayBuffer()`

   `INFO ...  INFO BlockManager: Removing RDD 4`

However, I don't see any actual **message** getting printed on the console.

Question: Why is my code not printing any actual messages?

My gradle dependencies are:

```
compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-core_2.10', version: '1.6.2'
compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-streaming_2.10', version: '1.6.2'
compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-streaming-kafka_2.10', version: '1.6.2'
```

Comment: Are you submitting the Spark job to a remote cluster?

Comment: Yes, now I'm submitting it to remote with the option `--master yarn`. I will update some of the logs in sometime. Removed the `setMaster(..)` API call in the beginning of code.

Comment: what is num of cores you are allocating for executor and how many executors are there  ?

Comment: **Check this link** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39565827/getting-empty-set-while-reading-data-from-kafka-spark-streaming/39587641#39587641

Answer (score 0):

stream is an object of JavaPairReceiverInputDStream. Convert it into Dstream and use foreachRDD to print the messages that are consumed from Kafka

Comment: didn't work. Now, I'm facing different issue. I'll update the question with findings.

Answer (score 0):

Spark 1.6.2 not support kafka 0.10 ,just support kafka0.8. For kafka 0.10 ,you should use spark 2

Comment: If that is the case, why isn't there any error indicating that?